# Network File Share Monitoring for Windows

Tags: windows, file-management

We are an IT Consultant looking to add some additional security for some of our clients. A few clients have been asking, "Show me everyone who has ever accessed this file". Well, we can't really do that without a 3rd party tool.

What we are looking for:

- Show a detailed logs of who accessed a network share or file

  - IP
  - Username
  - PC Name
  - Time
  - Read or Write
- The software needs to run as a service so we can install it on network file servers and have it run without being logged on.
- The logs should be searchable from within the software and take search parameters, such as date/time, username, filename

I have tried several tools so far and none seem to meet all the requirements. Some just downright do not work at all or show a user suddenly accessed every file in a share instantly. Or do not log the changes made to files at all.

We are looking for production, well-known software.

Comment: I assume Windows OS? Any price limit?

Comment: correct, windows OS. and no, no price limit.

Comment: There is a special tool 10-Strike Connection Monitor Pro exactly for your task. You can even configure a notification alert for some specific file or folder if you need this. The program records text logs and you can search it. The only problem is the username detection for the file deletion and creation events. http://www.10-strike.com/connectionmonitor/

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Windows file server with AD, this article should be able to do what you want, by logging everything to the EventLog:

[Auditing File Access on File Servers](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/08/26/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/)

Comment: Please post the relevant details here.  Answers consisting of just links aren't very helpful and are liable to be deleted.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution!